# export HTML Table to excel with grouping in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, export-to-excel

I have a problem to export HTML Table to excel with grouping in ASP.net.

this my code export to excel without grouping

Please help Me.

```
Dim sFileName As String = Session("UserName") + " " +cboCustomer.Text.Replace(",", "-") + ".xls"
Dim StrHtmlGenerate As New StringBuilder() Dim StrExport As New StringBuilder() 
Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel" 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName) 
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8 Dim tw As New StringWriter() 
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(tw) litTable.RenderControl(hw) Response.Write(tw.ToString()) 
Response.End()
```

Comment: Dim sFileName As String = Session("UserName") + " " + cboCustomer.Text.Replace(",", "-") + ".xls"
            Dim StrHtmlGenerate As New StringBuilder()
            Dim StrExport As New StringBuilder()
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName)
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            Dim tw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(tw)
            litTable.RenderControl(hw)
            Response.Write(tw.ToString())
            Response.End()

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code. Though its in C#, might be helpful for you.

```
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportToExcel.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write(HTMLDiv.InnerHtml);
        Response.End();
```

Where HTMLDiv is the HTML "div" element that contains the HTML

Comment: I create html table using <asp:Literal ID="litTable" runat="server" />

Comment: I create html table using <asp:Literal ID="litTable" runat="server" /> and in vb code like htmlTable.AppendLine("<table border=""1px"">") ...
                        htmlTable.AppendLine("</table >"). in your sample code where part to create a grouping in excel?

Comment: @Ishaq, refer this site for your further action

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankurmalik123/export-html-to-excel-and-more/